# How can i scape while loop at first time and further it will execute?

Tags: php, csv

I want that the while loop not execute at first time and after that it should print "hii".the purpose of doing that is when i upload csv file.i dont want to insert the header line of csv.

```
while (($data = fgetcsv($handle)) !== FALSE) {
    echo "hii";
}
```

Comment: If you know there is a line containing headers that you dont want, then just do a `$data = fgetcsv($handle);` BEFORE starting the while loop. Add a comment and Bob's your Uncle. Its easy and almost completly self documenting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this:

```
<?php
$row = 0;
if (($handle = fopen("test.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        $num = count($data);
        if ($row > 0)
        {
            echo "hiii";
        }
        $row++;
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
?>
```

Comment: Read and discard is sooo much simpler

Answer (score 1):

Without a counter - just call `fgetcsv` once without using it's result:

```
fgetcsv($handle);
echo 'hi!';
while (($data = fgetcsv($handle)) !== FALSE) {
    // other code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a counter:

```
$i = 0;
while (($data = fgetcsv($handle)) !== FALSE) {
    if ($i > 0) {
        echo "hii";
    }
    $i++;
}
```

Comment: Read and discard is sooo much simpler